# How to merge two mdx queries when I have used same dimension & Same Measure

Tags: union, mdx

I have to merge below two mdx queries results into one set.

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
      {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
      {[Product].[Category].&[4],
      [Product].[Category].&[1]} ON ROWS 
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Output is:

```
                Internet Sales Amount
 Accessories       $700,759.96 
 Bikes          $28,318,144.65
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
      {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
      {[Product].[Category].&[3]} ON ROWS 
FROM [Adventure Works]
where [Geography].[State-Province].&[WA]&[US]
```

Output is:

```
             Internet Sales Amount
Clothing    $339,772.61
```

I want to filter the region only for "clothing" Category but not for the other category.

But I want the results together. How to union these two result sets?

Final output should be:

```
        Internet Sales Amount
Accessories $700,759.96 
Bikes       $28,318,144.65 
Clothing    $339,772.61
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Product].[Category].[Clothing excl WA_US] AS 
    (
      [Product].[Category].&[3]
     ,[Geography].[State-Province].&[WA]&[US]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    [Product].[Category].&[4]
   ,[Product].[Category].&[1]
   ,[Product].[Category].[Clothing excl WA_US]
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Suspect this performs better:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    [Product].[Category].&[4]
   ,[Product].[Category].&[1]
   ,Exists
    (
      [Product].[Category].&[3]
     ,[Geography].[State-Province].&[WA]&[US]
    )
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```